# How to provide multiple users access in asp.net web application when sessionstate cookieless is set to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies

I have a web application which should be accessible to multiple users, however, the session becomes null after logging in two or several users

Here is my web config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="30"
               regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to address your issue using my imagination.

If you log in with some user and after logging in with others sessions become `null`, this should be something related to some application exception which makes the IIS application pool crash, and since I guess you're using *in-process session state*, when an application pool crashes or is recycled, all sessions are thrown away.

In other words: check if there's some exception that may produce an application pool crash.

Place an `Application_Error` event handler in your `Global.asax` and set a break point in there to detect an application crash.

### Update

As @b.pell has pointed out in some comment, sessions might go away because of out of memory issues.

I didn't mention that you can go for [database session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) storage, but sometimes isn't easier to switch to this mode because every object stored in your session will need to be serializable, and serialization/deserialization has an important impact in your overall application performance.

Comment: Downvote without justification... I believe I've tried to address the issue with a very possible description and solution, based on my own experience

Comment: I believe also the session can disappear if the server is under memory pressure and it's reclaiming memory aggressively.  I used to have sessions go poof all the time in shared hosting for that reason (you can setup the session to use a database and not be in proc if that's the issue).  (also, wasn't me that down voted). :D

Comment: @b.pell I can add that case in my answer... Thanks :)